# SELECT and DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, mysql-error-1093

I need to remove certain rows from a table. Which rows must be deleted is something I find out through a query. However, [it appears that you cannot do both operations (select and delete) in the same query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html):

> Currently, you cannot delete from a
>   table and select from the same table
>   in a subquery.

So I cannot do this:

```
DELETE
FROM telefono
WHERE telefono_id IN (
    SELECT te.telefono_id
    FROM telefono te
    LEFT JOIN centro_telefono ce ON te.telefono_id=ce.telefono_id AND ce.telefono_id IS NOT NULL
    LEFT JOIN contacto_telefono co ON te.telefono_id=co.telefono_id AND co.telefono_id IS NOT NULL
    WHERE COALESCE(ce.telefono_id, co.telefono_id) IS NULL AND te.fecha_alta < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
);
-- SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause
```

How can I implement this record clean-up in pure MySQL?

The server runs MySQL 5.1.39.

Comment: Why does it have to be in "pure" MySQL?

Comment: @NullUserException: I don't want to add an extra layer of complexity (writing a PHP script, configuring it via cron, testing whether it run successfully...). Furthermore, SQL code can be triggered directly from MySQL events or stored routines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the delete statement with the joins

```
DELETE te
FROM telefono as te
    LEFT JOIN centro_telefono ce
        ON te.telefono_id=ce.telefono_id AND ce.telefono_id IS NOT NULL
    LEFT JOIN contacto_telefono co
        ON te.telefono_id=co.telefono_id AND co.telefono_id IS NOT NULL
WHERE
    COALESCE(ce.telefono_id, co.telefono_id) IS NULL
    AND te.fecha_alta < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. This was my first attempt but I couldn't grasp the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable
 SELECT te.telefono_id
 FROM telefono te
  LEFT JOIN centro_telefono ce ON te.telefono_id=ce.telefono_id AND ce.telefono_id IS NOT NULL
  LEFT JOIN contacto_telefono co ON te.telefono_id=co.telefono_id AND co.telefono_id IS NOT NULL
  WHERE COALESCE(ce.telefono_id, co.telefono_id) IS NULL AND te.fecha_alta < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

 DELETE FROM telefono te
 WHERE te.telefono_id IN (Select telefono_id from tmptable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UPDATE` to mark rows for deletion, then `DELETE` to actually delete them.

```
UPDATE telefono SET marker_column='DELETE ME!!!!' WHERE telefono_id IN (...);
DELETE FROM telefono WHERE marker_column='DELETE ME!!!!';
```